# Tomcat Java error

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I am unable to start Tomcat due to lack of Java space.
Can you help me please?

I use
java version "1.7.0_55"
and
apache-tomcat-7.0.54
on a centos server

Here is the catalina logs

```
    Grave: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of directories to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the heapsize. Simply add the following line to `catalina.sh` file -

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

Set the size depending on your requirements.